# How set to default header and footer Nuxt.js?

Tags: node.js, templates, layout, nuxt.js

I started to learn Nuxt.js, and I like Nuxt.js!

But I faced problem:

I want to create header and footer layouts for all pages my application (analogue: `extends layout` for **pug**).

I found following way (`nuxt.config.js`):

```
router: {
        extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
            routes.push({
                name: 'custom',
                path: '*',
                component: resolve(__dirname, 'layouts/header.vue')
            })
        }
    },
```

But it is not right for me. :(

I found docs ([click me](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/views#layouts)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html {{ HTML_ATTRS }}>
  <head>
    {{ HEAD }}
  </head>
  <body {{ BODY_ATTRS }}>
    {{ APP }}
  </body>
</html>
```

And I want set options, where every page load for my pattern:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html {{ HTML_ATTRS }}>
  <head>
    {{ HEAD }}
  </head>
  <body {{ BODY_ATTRS }}>
    {{ HEADER}}
    {{ APP }}
    {{ FOOTER}}
  </body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to do something similar in Nuxt.js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just you have to be prepare layout under layout directory

and prepare 2 components for header and footer

so, layout template will be like below

```
<template>
<header_component>
</header_component>
</Nuxt>
<footer_component>
</footer_component>
</template>
```

Comment: thank you for help!
I did the following:
create two files in folder components (mainHeader.vue,mainFooter.vue ), and change default.vue (folder layouts):
`<template> <div>  <mainHeader />   <nuxt />  <mainFooter />  </div></template>`

and add to end file:  `import mainHeader from '~/components/mainHeader.vue'`, `export default { components: {  mainHeader } }`